# How to pass data from controller to service?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular service with a function:

```
// service.js

function DoSomething($resource) {
  var resourceUrl = 'right/here';
  return $resource(resourceUrl, {},  {
    'action': {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}
```

and a @RestController with 2 parameters (param1, param2).

When I use the service like this:

```
// service.js

function DoSomething($resource) {
  var resourceUrl =  'right/here';

  return $resource(resourceUrl, { param1: "abc", param2: "def" },  {
    'action': {
      method: 'POST'
    }
  });
}
```

It works fine. But when I want to pass these values from my controller, like this:

```
// controller.js

DoSomething.action(
  { param1: "abc" },
  { param2: "def" }
);
```

While service part remains empty

```
// service.js

return $resource(resourceUrl, {},  {
```

My @RestController receives only one value - the first from the left. How to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to pass `param1` & `param2` from controller?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do, I thought that was clear :)

Comment: Yes, just want to confirm and I have updated the answer below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$resource(resourceUrl, {},  {`, you can pass parameters from your controllwe as below,

```
//controller.js

DoSomething.action({}, {param1: "abc", param2: "def"});
```

Comment: It does not work :( I want to pass two separate values from my controller to my service, so that service can pass them to at RestController, which is defined like this: public void m(at RequestParam String param1, at RequestParam String param2);

Comment: The one you said `return $resource(resourceUrl, {param1:"abc", param2:"def"},  {` is working one right. And the controller is exactly sending the same and it should be like this. Since this object will be appended as `request body` json. Hence you cannot have two body objects. If you explain/post the code why your controller expects two parameters then I can suggest to change this

Comment: Can you post the controller code in the question? I will have a look.

Comment: It looks your spring @Restcontroller expects this as request param instead of request body

Comment: Instead of `RequestParam` you can try `RequestBody` in the @RestController

Comment: It's not much :)

        @PostMapping("right/here")
    public void doBusiness(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param2)
    {
        Result result = someService.getResult(param1,param2);
    }

Comment: Can you try `@RequestBody` Instead of `@RequestParam`, otherwise I can change the service a bit

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to create a new class in order to use @.RequestBody? Like public void doBusiness(@.RequestBody MyBody newBody); and then access its fields?

Comment: @tomwyn yes please, or if you can change the existing one thats good. Otherwise let me change the service to work with the current one

Comment: But it should be good with go with `@RequestBody` since your `http` method is `post`

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work with @.RequestBody! (It seems uglier though, that I had to create special class just to accomodate 2 variables. I'd still like to know if it's possible with @.RequestParams and specific bracket manipulation in controller/service).

Comment: @tomwyn Great :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the action method is a POST. A data object is required.

```
var paramObj = {param1: value1, param2: value2};
var dataObj = {};

DoSomething.action(paramObj, dataObj);
```

The parameters defined by the paramObj are appended as query parameters:

```
resourceUrl + "?param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

The dataObj is encoded as a JSON string and put in the body of the POST.

If the action method (POST) is invoked with only one argument:

```
DoSomething.action(dataObj);
```

The $resource service stringifies the dataObj and puts it in the body of the POST. URL parameters are taken from the defaults defined by the $resource.